# IIS server gives 406 error on trying to download .img file

Tags: http, iis

We have an embedded product that download its firmware upgrade via HTTP using a program called nvtools. This works from a linux server using Apache. But we switched to a Windows server using IIS. Now we are getting a: "406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page."

when trying to download the firmware update using nvtools. I can't change anything on the embedded system side to make this work. Our IT guy has not been able to fix this yet. What setting in IIS does he need to change to fix this issue?

One more thing, The file will download ok from a browser, or using wget on the embedded device. The issue is only with the firmware update program nvtools.

Dennis

Comment: Can you still run the old webserver and see what it sends over the wire? Then you can compare that to what IIS sends.  It might be something as simple as an optional header which nvtools does not understand.

Comment: Probably `nvtools` is setting the `Accept` header to something which IIS does not understand. You might be able to use the [`<mimeMap/>` element](https://docs.microsoft.com/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) to change the MIME-type that IIS thinks the file is to exactly match the client’s `Accept:` header.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the MIME type in IIS.  Here are the directions:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
2. In Features View, double-click MIME Types.
3. In the Actions pane, click Add.
4. In the Add MIME Type dialog box, type a file name extension in the File name extension text box. For example, type .xyz.
5. Type a MIME type in the MIME type text box. For example, type application/octet-stream.
6. Click OK.